# Concatenate the rows based on number (Google Refine, Excel/Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, openrefine

I have large amount of rows on a csv file, which look like:

```
name a,1
name b,1
name c,1
name d,2
name e,2
```

I need to concatenate the rows based on number. Result should be:

```
name a|name b|name c
name d|name e
```

How can I do it in Google Refine or in Excel/Google Spreadsheet?

I am thinking of it, but with no solution.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Are you sure those are your only two options? This would be like 10 lines in Python.

Comment: Please can you show me how to solve it in python. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposal with Open refine. The only Grel formula i used is:

```
row.record.cells['myColumn'].value.join('|')
```

[screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubRDB.gif)

And here is the JSOn, assuming that your first column is named "myColumn" and the second "number" :

```
[
  {
    "op": "core/column-addition",
    "description": "Create column test at index 2 based on column number using expression grel:value",
    "engineConfig": {
      "mode": "row-based",
      "facets": [
        {
          "omitError": false,
          "expression": "isBlank(value)",
          "selectBlank": false,
          "selection": [
            {
              "v": {
                "v": false,
                "l": "false"
              }
            }
          ],
          "selectError": false,
          "invert": false,
          "name": "ee",
          "omitBlank": false,
          "type": "list",
          "columnName": "ee"
        }
      ]
    },
    "newColumnName": "test",
    "columnInsertIndex": 2,
    "baseColumnName": "number",
    "expression": "grel:value",
    "onError": "set-to-blank"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-move",
    "description": "Move column test to position 0",
    "columnName": "test",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "op": "core/blank-down",
    "description": "Blank down cells in column test",
    "engineConfig": {
      "mode": "row-based",
      "facets": [
        {
          "omitError": false,
          "expression": "isBlank(value)",
          "selectBlank": false,
          "selection": [
            {
              "v": {
                "v": false,
                "l": "false"
              }
            }
          ],
          "selectError": false,
          "invert": false,
          "name": "ee",
          "omitBlank": false,
          "type": "list",
          "columnName": "ee"
        }
      ]
    },
    "columnName": "test"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-addition",
    "description": "Create column concatenation at index 2 based on column myColumn using expression grel:row.record.cells['myColumn'].value.join('|')",
    "engineConfig": {
      "mode": "row-based",
      "facets": [
        {
          "omitError": false,
          "expression": "isBlank(value)",
          "selectBlank": false,
          "selection": [
            {
              "v": {
                "v": false,
                "l": "false"
              }
            }
          ],
          "selectError": false,
          "invert": false,
          "name": "ee",
          "omitBlank": false,
          "type": "list",
          "columnName": "ee"
        }
      ]
    },
    "newColumnName": "concatenation",
    "columnInsertIndex": 2,
    "baseColumnName": "myColumn",
    "expression": "grel:row.record.cells['myColumn'].value.join('|')",
    "onError": "set-to-blank"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I hope to learn from this tool. At the moment this response has been of great help

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Python it would be pretty easy to do this manipulation. In the the code below, the name and group are read from "input.csv", and the grouped names (along with the group) are written to "output.csv". A `defaultdict` is used to create empty lists to store the group members.

```py
import collections
import csv

grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('input.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        name, group = row
        grouped[group].append(name)


with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='|')
    for key in sorted(grouped.keys()):
        writer.writerow([key] + grouped[key])
```